# Team Foundation Services: Adding non-project file to source control

Tags: version-control, visual-studio-2012, azure-devops

I'm trying out the new Team Foundation Services and I'm wondering how people manage source control of non-VS-Project files. So my solution is added to the TFS source control, but if there's some Word Templates, Crystal Report files, etc that aren't part of the solution, but are supplementary to the application that need to be source controlled as well how would I go about doing that?

Thanks

Comment: Just add them to source control. I've been using TFS for 7 years and have stored all manner of non code artefacts in it. I seem to be missing the problem you're having. Please expand your question with what you don't seem to be able to do and how you want to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you installed the Team Explorer into Visual Studio - I suspect you have.

[Use Source Control Explorer to Manage Files under Version Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms181370.aspx)

- Open Source Control Explorer
- Do one of the following:

  - From the menu bar choose View, Other Windows, Source Control Explorer.
  - From Team Explorer, choose  Home, and then choose Source Control Explorer.

[image]

Then in the Source Tree just right click and select Add Files.

See here for lots more info [Working within Team Explorer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500420.aspx)